# Application specific logs not getting generated in JBoss EAP 7.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, jboss-eap-7

I have developed an application using Spring Boot and deployed that in JBoss EAP 7.3.0server. The application is writing the application specific logs in a separate log file (not server.log of JBoss) and we are using log4j for logging. The name and path where the lo would be generated is specified in log4j.properties placed in the classpath of the application. This setup is working correctly and logs are getting generated in one of our environments but logs are not getting generated in another environment. We are suspecting that the logger is not defined in JBoss in the environment where the logs are not getting generated. Can anyone please say from where to check the logger configuration of JBoss and how to ensure whether all the configurations are correct so that the logs will get generated?

Note: The JBoss server.log is getting generated correctly in all the environments.

Comment: Have you made any specific changes to the logging subsystem or do you explicitly exclude it or any dependencies in a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in your deployment?

Comment: There is some other team who is maintaining the JBoss, from application perspective, we have not excluded any logs in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. It would be helpful if I know where we define the loggers in JBoss or where to look in JBoss for this issue.

Comment: How do you configure logging? Also if you're not excluding the logging subsystem or logging dependencies make sure you're not including logging JAR's in your deployment.

Comment: We are using log4j for logging in our application and the file to which the logs are generated from each application is configured in log4j.properties. i will paste the log4j.properties file here.

Comment: Do you include the log4j library in your deployment?

Comment: Yes the log4j library is included in deployment

Comment: Try removing all the log4j libraries from the deployment.

Comment: I have modified the question and asked again with a few more analysis at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587601/logs-are-not-written-in-application-specific-log-files-in-jboss-eap-7-3