# Logs are not written in application specific log files in JBoss EAP 7.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, log4j, jboss-eap-7

I have developed my application using Spring Boot and deploying the application as war file in JBoss EAP 7.3 server. Below is the dependencies section of pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-base64</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-naming-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

We also have log4j jar files added as resources in module.xml. Below are the log4j jar file references in modules.xml:

```
<resource-root path="./ext/log4j-1.2-api.jar"/>
<resource-root path="./lib/log4j-api.jar"/> 
<resource-root path="./lib/log4j-core.jar"/>
```

Logs are generated from my application when I am writing the logs in server.log of JBoss. But logs are not getting generated when I am writing the logs in an application specific log file, the path of which I am specifying in log4j.propertes of my application. Logs are getting generated in the application specific log file when the following is removed from modules.xml:

```
<resource-root path="./ext/log4j-1.2-api.jar"/>
```

Can anyone please suggest what changes I need to do in the pom.xml file for generating the logs in application specific log file?

Comment: What logging facade are you using? It looks like maybe slf4j. Do you have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` which excludes slf4j somehow?

Comment: No I do not have jboss-deployment structure.xml

Comment: Do I need to exclude the module <module name="org.slf4j" /> in jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Comment: If you want slf4j to use log4j2 as the log manager yes.